# Analysis of impulse response in downsampling problem

Tags: signal-analysis, impulse-response

[image]

Hey everyone, I'm stuck on this problem and I've got an exam in a few days. I think the filter H is used here so as to avoid aliasing artifacts, and afterwards went on to the second question.

I've got using my notebook

$g(n) = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} G(e^{i2\pi v}) \cdot e^{i2\pi vn} \, dv$
$g(n) = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{i\pi v(2n+1)} \, dv$
$g(n) = -\frac{1}{{i\pi(1+2n)}} \left(e^{i\pi(n+1/2)}-e^{-i\pi(n+1/2)}\right)$

But I have absolutely no idea where to go from here. Please help!
Thank you.

Comment: hint: $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2j}(e^{jx} - e^{-jx})$

Comment: Thank you so much! I found that the filter was stable but not causal. Would you have any idea how to do the c) 1) ?

Comment: I'll keep editing my answer with hints as you work your way through.

Comment: I'm finding $U(z) = \frac{1}{2} (X(z) + X(z)z^{-1}G(z^2)$ But I'm not sure how to express $G(z^2)$ Into $G(z)$

Comment: Try leaving it as $G(z^2)$ and move on to the next question

Answer (score 1):

b 1): hint: $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2j}(e^{jx} - e^{-jx})$

c 1): hint: do it in the $\mathcal{Z}$ domain: $U(z) = \frac{1}{2} (X(z) + X(z)z^{-1} \cdots)$